# Sum of the digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, int, typeerror

I want to get the sum of the digits of an integer, and found the solutions below:

1. `sum(map(int,list(str(123))))`
2. `sum(int(digit) for digit in str(123))`

However, when I run this, I get the below error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Did you set the name `sum` to an integer?

Comment: @khelwood: Or `str`, or, in the former example, `list`. Point is, this is clearly a name-shadowing conflict; don't name variables the same as built-ins. If this is an interactive session you don't want to restart, run `del sum`, `del list`, `del str` (ignore any errors) and your code should work fine.

Comment: [Works for me](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Eo7g0VyM3sUADyNbJySwGCpQUaRgaGWuCwP//AA)

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to other answers, both your code works fine.

I think you are shadowing something on your code. Perhaps you used `int` as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) works on iterables.

```
int(digit) for digit in str(123)
```

This returns an generator, and should work, as said by other answers, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension).

The below should also do the job:

```
sum([int(digit) for digit in '123'])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `sum(int(digit) for digit in str(123))` is valid Python working as intended. If your function has only one argument, then you're not required to use round brackets / parenthesis to write a generator expression. Check [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) for more details.

Comment: Edited. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(int(digit) for digit in str(123))
```

The above code should work.

However you said you get the error,

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

That error suggests that you're using type `int` instead of a `str`
.
Did you use another variable for that?
For example, the below code should give you that error you mentioned

```
obj = 123
sum(int(digit) for digit in obj)
```

You have to ensure that `obj` is of a `str` type.

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` works in iterable objects. You need to create a list with the digits you are trying to add. The code below should do that:

```
sum([int(x) for x in str(123)])
```

Comment: `sum(int(digit) for digit in str(123))` is valid Python working as intended. If your function has only one argument, then you're not required to use round brackets / parenthesis to write a generator expression. Check [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) for more details.